# Find the I/O cost of the following question?

Tags: database-design, query-performance, data

Estimate the I/O cost of retrieving records from Parts table that contains price less than or equal 1000 rupees. Assume that 15% of tuples satisfy the selection criteria. There are 3300 pages in the Parts table, with 50 records each page. The clustered B+ tree index on price attribute is the only index available in the Parts table. This index takes up 1/3 of the table's space.

Comment: Homework is it. Please show what you have done and ask one question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Knowing which database system this is in the context of is probably important here, since different systems may use different page sizes (depending on the units you want to measure I/O in I suppose).

Comment: Aren't the "pages" likely to be cached in RAM?